# Transformar programa python em executavel com banco de dados

Tags: mysql, python

Eu criei um programa em python bem simples para organizar meus trabalhos e provas, mas gostaria de tornar ele portável para usar em qualquer computador. Eu conheço o pyinstaller e o cx_Freeze para transformar os apps em executaveis, mas eu gostaria de saber como que fica a parte do banco de dados, ja que seria muita coisa colocar um banco de dados MySQL com o Wamp Server num pendrive por exemplo. O que eu posso fazer? Abaixo vai meu código:

```
import pymysql as sql
import os
import pandas as pd

conexao = sql.connect(db = 'trabalhos', user = 'root', passwd = '')
cursor = conexao.cursor()

def Deleta_Trabalho():
    print("Digite -1 para cancelar ou digite o ID do trabalho abaixo: \n")
    opcao = int(input("Digite o ID: \n"))
    if opcao < 0:
        Consulta_Trabalhos()

    elif opcao == 0:
        Consulta_Trabalhos()

    else:
        Comando = ("Delete from trabalhos Where  ID = {0}")
        Comando_Final = Comando.format(opcao)
        cursor.execute(Comando_Final)
        conexao.commit()
        print("Trabalho Deletado! \n")
        Consulta_Trabalhos()

def Deleta_Avaliacao():
    print("Digite -1 para cancelar ou digite o ID da avaliacao abaixo: \n")
    opcao = int(input("Digite o ID: \n"))
    if opcao < 0:
        Consulta_Avaliacoes()

    elif opcao == 0:
        Consulta_Avaliacoes()

    else:
        Comando = ("Delete from avaliacoes Where  ID = {0}")
        Comando_Final = Comando.format(opcao)
        cursor.execute(Comando_Final)
        conexao.commit()
        print("Avaliacao Deletada! \n")
        Consulta_Avaliacoes()

def Consulta_Trabalhos():
    frame = pd.read_sql('Select * From trabalhos', conexao)
    pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
    print(frame)    

    escolha = int(input("1 - Voltar ao Menu Inicial     2 - Deletar Trabalho    3 - Sair \n"))

    if escolha == 1:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        return 1

    elif escolha == 2:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        Deleta_Trabalho()

    elif escolha == 3:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        return 5
def Consulta_Avaliacoes():
    frame = pd.read_sql('Select * From avaliacoes', conexao)
    pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
    print(frame)

    escolha = int(input("1 - Voltar ao Menu Inicial     2 - Deletar Avaliacao    3 - Sair \n"))

    if escolha == 1:
        return 1

    elif escolha == 2:
        Deleta_Avaliacao()

    elif escolha == 3:
        return 5

def Novo_Trabalho():
    Materia = input("Qual a materia? \n")

    Dia = input("Dia: \n")

    Mes = input("Mes: \n")

    Data = Dia + "/" + Mes + "/" + "2020"

    Sobre = input("Fale sobre o trabalho: ")

    Comando = "Insert into trabalhos (Materia, Data_Entrega, Descricao) Values ('{0}', STR_TO_DATE( '{1}' , '%d/%m/%Y'), '{2}')"

    Comando_Final = Comando.format(Materia, Data, Sobre)

    cursor.execute(Comando_Final)

    conexao.commit()

    return True

def Nova_Avaliacao():
    Materia = input("Qual a materia? \n")

    Dia = input("Dia: \n")

    Mes = input("Mes: \n")

    Data = Dia + "/" + Mes + "/" + "2020"

    Conteudo = input("Conteudo: \n")

    Comando = "Insert into avaliacoes (Materia, `Data`, Conteudo) Values ('{0}', STR_TO_DATE( '{1}' , '%d/%m/%Y'), '{2}')"

    Comando_Final = Comando.format(Materia, Data, Conteudo)

    cursor.execute(Comando_Final)

    conexao.commit()

    return True

def main():
    print("1 - Ver trabalhos \n")

    print("2 - Ver avaliações \n")

    print("3 - Novo trabalho \n")

    print("4 - Nova avaliação \n")

    print("5 - Sair \n")

    escolha = int(input("Digite o que deseja fazer: \n"))

    if escolha == 1:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        Consulta_Trabalhos()

    elif escolha == 2:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        Consulta_Avaliacoes()

    elif escolha == 3:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        sucesso = Novo_Trabalho()

        if sucesso == True:
            print("Trabalho agendado com sucesso! \n")
            print("Veja todos os trabalhos: \n")
            opcao = Consulta_Trabalhos()

            if opcao == 1:
                return 1

            elif opcao == 5:
                conexao.close()
                return 5


    elif escolha == 4:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        sucesso = Nova_Avaliacao()


        if sucesso == True:
            print("Avaliacao agendada com sucesso! \n")
            print("Veja todos as avaliacoes: \n")
            Consulta_Avaliacoes()

    elif escolha == 5:
        return 5

x = main()

while x != 5:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    x = main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas opções.
Trabalhar com algum banco em uma maquina virtual e conecta seu app a ele.

ou

Migrar seu banco de dados para um banco sqlite.
ele é um banco de dados local(Um arquivo) onde quem faz o controles de transação e conexão são as classes do próprio python.

é um banco muito simples de se usar, e caso conheça ORM, pode utilizar o sqlalchemy para facilitar sua interação com o DB.

Comment: Opa Willian, obrigado mesmo, isso vai me ajudar muito!